On Shafarevich's proof that $k[\mathbb{P}^n] = k$ for $k$ algebraically closed
I am confused by Shafarevich's proof that $k[\mathbb{P}^n] = k$ for $k$ algebraically closed. It goes as follows:

Assume $f =P/Q$ on the $\mathbb{P}^n$, where $P$ and $Q$ are forms of same degree. We can assume $P$ and $Q$ have no common factors (over alg. closed field - no common roots). Then $f$ is not regular in the roots of $Q(x)$; therefore for $f$ to be regular over all of the space, the only option is that $Q(x)$ is constant, and then $P(x)$ is also constant.

Based on my understanding of Shafarevich's definition of regular functions, $f = P/Q$ is only a local representation of $f$, which means that for those points $x$ with $Q(x)$, there might be another representation $f = P_1/Q_1$ with $Q_1(x) \neq 0$. So $f$ could be regular on $x$ even if $Q(x) \neq 0$. Could you please help me understand this proof? Thanks in advance!

Personally, I think one may deduce that the regular function $f$ can be represented globally as a polynomial on $\mathbb{P}^n$, from the same procedure that is used in the affine case. Since $f$ is also homogeneous of degree $0$, this polynomial must be a constant. Is this proof correct?

I don't know what Shafarevich's proof is, but $\mathbb P^n$ is covered by charts that are isomorphic to $\mathbb A^n$, and any globally defined function would have to restrict to a function on each of those charts.  If you look at two different charts, then by comparing things on the overlap of the charts, you can say things about what the various restrictions must look like.

If $f$ is a regular function on $\Bbb P^n$, then it is certainly a rational function on $\Bbb P^n$, and every rational function on $\Bbb P^n$ is a ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree. These are Shafarevich's $P$ and $Q$.
Now suppose that $f=P/Q$ for coprime homogeneous $P,Q$ of the same degree, and $P(x)\neq 0$, $Q(x)=0$ for some $x\in\Bbb P^n$. If there is a local representation of $f$ near $x$ as $P_1/Q_1$ with $Q_1(x)\neq 0$, then we have $P(x)Q_1(x) = P_1(x)Q(x)$, but the LHS is nonzero while the RHS is zero. So there's no way to choose a local representation of $f$ so that $f$ is regular at a root of $Q$ which is not a root of $P$.
Therefore if $f=P/Q$ is regular, all roots of $Q$ must also be roots of $P$, or $V(Q)\subset V(P)$, giving $P\in \sqrt{(Q)}$. But $P$ and $Q$ are coprime, so $Q$ must be constant, and therefore $f$ must be constant too.

Thank you! That is quite clear. I think that is what Shafarevich actually means.

Also, it seems that I can prove $f$ has a global representation as a polynomial $F$, and it follows that $P/Q$ coincides with $F$ on an open set, hence also on the whole $\mathbb{P}^n$, which means that $F$ must be a constant. Does this proof work?

Probably not - nonconstant polynomials are not functions on $\Bbb P^n$, so that should prevent the proof from working, but I'd need to see more details of your proposed proof to point out the specific flaw.

I have detailed my proof in an answer below. Could you help to point out the specific flaw? Thanks in advance.

The original question has been answered perfectly by KReiser. I have proposed a proof of the same proposition, which seems to be flawed as suggested in KReiser's comment. I detail the proof here so that everyone can help point out the specific flaw.
The proof goes by two steps. First I show that $f$ has a global representation as a polynomial $F$. Denote by $Y$ the set of all points where $f$ is regular. For $y\in Y$, there exists a representation $f = P_y/Q_y$ with $Q_y(y)\neq 0$. Now let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the ideal generated by all the $Q_y$'s. Since $f$ is regular on $\Bbb{P}^n$, $Z(\mathfrak{a}) = Y$ is empty. It follows from Nullstellensatz that $\mathfrak{a}$ contains $1$, i.e. $$\sum_y H_y Q_y = 1\,\,\,\,(1)$$ for finitely many $Q_y$'s. Because the set $W$ on which $P_y = Q_y f$ is a closed set, containing the open (hence also dense) set $U_y = \{x\in \Bbb{P}^n \mid Q_y(x)\neq 0\}$, $W = \Bbb{P}^n$. Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $f$, one has $f = \sum_y H_y P_y$, that is, $f$ can be represented as a polynomial $f = F$.
Next I show that $F$ must be constant. Let $f=P/Q$, which is a representation for $f$ over the open (hence also dense) set $U = \{x\in \Bbb{P}^n \mid Q(x)\neq 0\}$. Notice that this representation must coincide with $f = F$ on $U$, since $f = F$ holds globally on $\Bbb{P}^n$. But then $\{x\in \Bbb{P}^n \mid Q(x) F(x) - P(x) = 0\}$ is a closed set containing $U$, which means it is exactly $\Bbb{P}^n$. Calculating degree for both sides of the equation $Q(x) F(x) = P(x)$, one sees that $F$ is of degree $0$, that is, $F$ is a constant.

I think this may be better off as a new question, but is one problem to start you off: it does not follow from the Nullstellensatz that $\mathfrak{a}$ contains $1$ - we could instead have $\mathfrak{a}$ be the irrelevant ideal. You'll need to use the projective nullstellensatz here, which you haven't done.

@KReiser Thank you for pointing out the flaw. The projective Nullstellensatz only implies that for each homogeneous coordinate $S_i$, $f = \frac{\sum_y H_y^i P_y}{S_i}$. And then one has to compare expressions of $f$ for different $i$'s to conclude that the numerator in the expression is also divided by $S_i$, which makes this argument essentially the same as the standard proof given in your answer.

Also, the zero set $W$ equation $P_y = Q_y f$ seems not to be well-defined in the context, which is another problem.
